Scala circe: encode List to json as flat string
The task is to encode:
 List(1,2,3)

to the the following string:
 [1,2,3]

By applying  io.circe.asJson - function:
List(1,2,3).asJson

I receive the following output:
[
   1,
   2,
   3
]

What am I doing wrong?

Well a JSON is not a String, is a data type. You can use a Printer to produce a String out of it. There is a Printer that produces results without spaces, take a look to that. Also, JSON has a couple of helper methods like printNoSpaces

What do you mean with applying asJson you are getting that result? Are you passing that value to println? Like println(List(1,2,3).asJson)? Share the code that is producing that output to see what you are doing

Keep in mind that from a JSON point of view, both are representing the exact same data. It's just a matter of "pretty print" or not.

Short answer
You need to call noSpaces explicitly to get result you want
List(1, 2, 3).asJson.noSpaces


Longer answer
List(1, 2, 3).asJson construction call extension method asJson on instance of the list, the output of that method will be an instance of Json object, that resembles a Json AST.
def asJson(implicit encoder: Encoder[A]): Json

When you print it via println or in scala cli, it will call method toString on the Json instance, which by default an alias to spaces2 method. The method as it stands from the name prints json with 2 space indentation (aka pretty print).
You might discover several ready methods on the Json class responsible for printing:

spaces2 - pretty print with 2 space indentation
spaces4 - pretty print with 4 space indentation
noSpaces - print without spaces
all of the methods above have version with key sorting *SortKeys

Alternatively, if you want to customise printing further you can configure existing Printer (io.circe.Printer) or implement custom one. For example, if I want to drop optional or null values I can do:
// case class with optional value
case class Sample(value: Option[String]) derives Encoder
// custom printer
val noNulls = Printer.noSpaces.copy(dropNullValues = true)
// pass custom printer to json
Sample(None).asJson.printWith(noNulls)
// result {}, normally it would be {"value": null}

